# Redirect cmdlet warning/error output?

Tags: powershell

This must be a very simple solution, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to redirect errors/warnings to standard output.

Right now, I'm capturing the output of stuff by assigning it to a variable, without worrying about formatting etc, so for example:

```
$buffer += Whatever-Cmdlet
```

But what I would like to do is also capture any error message into that variable. Like doing 2>&1.

Is there any way to make this work? I did try:

```
$buffer += Whatever-Cmdlet 2>&1
```

without success.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Not tested thoroughly, but

```
$buffer += Whatever-Cmdlet -WarningVariable +buffer -ErrorVariable +buffer
```

if you have v3/4:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{"*:WarningVariable"="+buffer";"*:ErrorVariable"="+buffer";}
```

Should do it for all the cmdlets your run after you set that.

Comment: Hadn't seen the "+" syntax with WarningVariable and ErrorVariable.

Comment: Note that the use of `PSDefaultParameterValues` requires V3 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it turns out as long as you pipe the output:

```
$buffer += Whatever-Cmdlet 2>&1 | Out-String
```

It seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's exactly how you do it with .EXEs. However that doesn't work with cmdlets. In other words something like `get-process 2>&1` won't do what you are describing, but `cmd /c type myfile.txt 2>&1` will.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of PowerShell you're running. In PowerShell v2 warnings are written to the host and thus cannot be captured in a variable. In PowerShell v3 warnings are written to a separate output stream, so you have to redirect the warning stream as well as the error stream to capture errors and warnings:

```
$buffer += Whatever-Cmdlet 2>&1 3>&1 | Out-String
```

See [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) for more information.